# App launches when DLL in .exe folder, pops an error if DLL in System32 (error 0xc0000428 “<dll name> is either not designed to run on windows…”)

Tags: windows-8, dll

We have an app (test tool), if I run the exe and have the DLL in the same library, it works correctly. If I move the DLL to c:\windows\system32 and try the exe, it fails with the following message.
Windows 8.1 tablet.

Any clues what might be going on? Also tried to sign the DLL, no go.

" is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing...... Error status 0xc0000428"

Comment: Sounds like the program was designed to only look in the folder where its located.  TThis is actually correct behavior.

Comment: when you say win 8.1 tablet, are you on an ARM or x86 platform? not that I expect your dll to work from any folder if it was compiled for the wrong platform.

Comment: @FrankThomas - ARM

Answer (score 0):

What ever kind of .exe this is clearly needs to be run in the same directory as the .dll. The executable cannot find the .dll, a necessary resource for the app to run correctly, if outside of the same working directory. Unless you are (or know) the programmer who designed the application, it's unlikely there is an option to have the executable find this .dll if not in the same directory. You may consider making a shortcut to the .exe and keep the .exe+.dll paired in another directory.

Comment: Hi,
The error message if the DLL is not found at all is totally different, and it actually says the the DLL is missing.

Comment: Can you move the entire folder, including the .exe(s) and .dll(s) to another directory and run it from there? This sounds very situationally specific and without details on the application it becomes increasingly hard to diagnose.

Comment: @ranshe - It is.  Its not in the location where the program was designed to look for it.

Comment: I can run the app from anywhere as long as the DLL is in the same folder.
In previous versions, I could also run it w/ DLL in System32.
In this version (and previous), if the DLL is missing altogether, the error that comes back is that the DLL is missing, so it does know to look for it in System32.

Comment: @ranshe Can you test that?

Comment: @root - tested moving the app over, it does work from anywhere if the DLL is w/ the exe, it pops up the same error msg if it's in system32.
Seems like this happened w/ many apps (search on Google), but the responses have not helped me so far (see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/message-keeps-popping-out-saying-that-cprogram/b129bf31-3468-4493-9ee1-a72618abb000 as an example)

Comment: @ranshe - Don't base what you could do in a previous version of the program.  Its very likely the program was updated to only look in a single location, historically, it shouldn't be system32 anyways.

Comment: @Ramhound - it's a service DLL which has to be in System32. The exe is just a test app, so that's the only case it *shouldn't* be in system32

Comment: @ranshe - I have no idea what a "service" dll is exactly.  This sounds like a programming problem.  When you compile the software do you compile the program with the dll in the System32 location or the local directory?

Answer (score 0):

There may be two versions of the DLL (with the same name) on the system, one that's compatible with your system, and one that isn't.

When you have the 'right' DLL in the folder with the EXE, that's the first place it checks, and therefore finds the right one, and uses it.

If you move this working DLL to System32, it's in the PATH, but it's now further down the search order list.  How much further down depends on your PATH.

If the non-working version of the DLL ends up in the search order ahead of the one you moved to System32, then the program will try to use that version (since it found it first).

Search all folders on your system for other versions of that DLL, and (re)move it if possible, to get it out of the DLL path search order.

Comment: That's a good idea - I'll have the device back in a few hours and will try that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a signature issue.
Once we enabled Audit Mode, we were good (no more error message).
We will sort out which party needs to sign which component, but at least we know where to look.

Thanks to all who participated.